# Provide contents of file field at node URL

Tags: files

I'm trying to set up my Drupal website to host files (more specifically, PDFs) at clean URL's and have some download statistics about them. For example, I would like "test.pdf" to be available at "/publications/test.pdf". I read about all the file managers such as IMCE, but they do not seem to provide this feature. Therefore I'm now trying to set up a Publication content type with just a single field of type File, use the URL path settings to get the clean URL and use the Download Count module to provide me some download statistics. However, I cannot seem to have Drupal return the PDF in the file field when a user visits the URL of such a node. The closest I get is rendering a link to the file, using the display settings of the file field.

Is this the way to go for what I want to achieve? And if so, how can I provide the contents of a file field at the URL of the node containing that field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a good idea to provide contents of file field at node URL.

Instead use [File Aliases module](https://drupal.org/project/file_aliases) which will let you use node properties in the resulting file url.

> The File Aliases module allows you to use token customizable aliases
>   for your uploaded files, giving you the ability to keep your file
>   system organized as per usual while providing clean looking paths
>   (i.e., no more '/sites/default/files/').

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Gokul N K is the way to go. However, some refinements to save those looking to use this module some time:

- The current version (7.x-1.0-beta1) has some bugs. These have been fixed by a [great patch](https://drupal.org/node/1896326). To apply this patch though, you need version 7.x-1.x-dev dated 2011-Nov-15. This is not the development version with the same name, so fetch the version from november 2011 using the repository viewer.
- Then, to use the module: construct a content type, add a File field and look into the settings of that field. Took me forever to find out :)

Thanks!