# Automatically open linked pdf (bypassing download box)

Tags: nodes, files

I've created a Content type that allows me to upload files (specifically pdf's).

After uploading a pdf file and then linking to it in a static document, clicking the link gives me a download page.
[image]

I want the link to open the pdf directly. I tried the recommendation at http://www.drupalgardens.com/content/file-content-type
but get a similar page, without the link.
[image]

Assistance in fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Try it for yourself**

There are three bulleted links on the page: 
 http://roguepublishing.ca/content/Communicating_Science

The regular 'Table of contents' leads to a page with one URL on it. That is the same URL as the hard-coded 'Table of contents'. As you can see, using these links opens the pdf's.

The 'Resource' Content type has
 * Enable Display field is checked
 * Files displayed by default is checked
 * The Manage Display is set to "URL to file"
If I change Manage Display to "Table of files", I get a table with a link to the file. Clicking that link launches the pdf.

*Simply: how do I get Drupal to launch the pdf from the alias on the first page?*

Comment: Are you using File Entity and/or Media?

Comment: No. I set the allowed file types when creating the Content Type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provide contents of file field at node URL](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102090/provide-contents-of-file-field-at-node-url)

Comment: I've talked with neRok who is at the link provided by Gokul N K. It is not the same problem; File Alias cannot solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are just linking to files, and the default action for the browser to take is to ask to download the file.
Files will sometimes automatically open if the browser is set up to do so.
If you want to make sure the pdf is always displayed, you will have to look into pdf viewer modules. Here is a site that compares a few.
https://drupal.org/node/1781960

Comment: I've added the TRY IT FOR YOURSELF to the original post so you can test it on your system.

Comment: "Thanks for thinking I'm a complete idiot." I'm sorry, but I was just trying to help you with the question you asked before it was edited. With that attitude, you will get no more help from me.

Comment: @ 2pha: not a problem. Even with my limited knowledge of Drupal, I know your answer is non-sensical. The images in the original post are clearly not those of the browser asking  what action to take.

Answer (score 1):

#### **Closing this discussion**

I am surprised that Drupal has such advanced functionality in core, but such a simple task requires an external module. Apparently, [File Entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) will do this, but I haven't figured out how. Yet.
I have summarized and generalized the problem at https://drupal.org/node/2207001

Thanks,
Roy Jensen